# LSTM accuracy VS F1-score

Tags: keras, lstm, word2vec

I am trying to do multi-classification on imbalanced data with 3 classes. The imbalance is something like 6:1:3. The total amount of samples is 7000.

I use LSTM, and Word2Vec to vectorize the data. Stop words and weird characters were also removed.

I have 3 features, and created 3 competing LSTM models of the same structure (because Word2Vec takes only one column), so that each model is trained on each vectorized feature separately to preserve the context of that data.

I ended up having good accuracy during the training and bad accuracy during validation. With F1-score (which is supposed to be a good fit for imbalanced data), it started with good F1-score, but both validation and train F1-score just went down over time.

[image]
[image]

I am looking for some tips how to improve or fix this situation.

Comment: Are you sure the bottom graph is showing F1-*score*? It starts at > 1.0, but [the highest possible value of an F-score is 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score).

Comment: Most likely you have mistaken some *loss* with *score*.